# Understanding different genetic terminology - Genotype vs SNP

Tags: gene, snp

I recently came across a study that refereed to variations in genes like this:

IGF1 (CA)19/(CA)19, IGF1(CA)19/X, IGF1 X/X

(From this study: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3274549/)

I wanted to know, as a member of 23andme, how I could check these "markers" (?) against the SNP's listed in 23andme.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Here are list of tools that you can use now that you have you DNA raw data: https://www.xcode.life/23andme-raw-data/23andme-raw-data-analysis-interpretation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "IGF1" at the front indicates that the genetic variation is in the gene for Insulin-like Growth Factor 1. The notation (CA)<sub>n</sub> is used to describe *n* adjacent repetitions of the two-base sequence CA (Cytosine, Adenine) present in a particular IGF1 DNA sequence. Hence IGF1 (CA)<sub>19</sub> / (CA)<sub>19</sub> is referring to a genome in which both copies of the IGF1 gene have 19 adjacent repetitions of the CA pair of bases, that is, which is [homozygous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygosity) for IGF1 (CA)<sub>19</sub>.

Such a repeat is usually called a *microsatellite* or [*Short Tandem Repeat* (STR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite). They are common sources of variations in genes because the DNA matching process during [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis) sometimes "slips" one or two repeats over.

The type of test performed by 23andMe reports values for selected SNPs (Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms).  SNPs are a different kind of variation from STRs, so the data available from 23andMe does not allow you to determine the kind of IGF1 (CA)<sub>n</sub> variant present.